# Python - Compare two lists and find matching values and their positions in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a turn based RPG and I am currently working on the turn system.

To keep it simple for now I am trying to order each character/enemy by their speed and then highest speed goes first. Below is the start of my code for the turn system.

An example of what I want to do is read `Order[0]` (which will be the fasted character/enemy) and find out which character/enemy that relates to. `Speed[0]` to `Speed[3]` gives the speed of my 4 characters and `enemySpeed[0]` to `enemySpeed[4]` gives the speed of the 5 enemies.

```
def Turn():
    Turn = [int(Speed[0]), int(Speed[1]), int(Speed[2]), int(Speed[3]), int(enemySpeed[0]), int(enemySpeed[1]),int(enemySpeed[2]), int(enemySpeed[3]), int(enemySpeed[4])]
    Order = sorted(Turn, key = int, reverse = True)
```

Edit: Here is some information regarding player stats.
In main():

```
    name = ['Ben','Ellis','Curt','Jen']
    HP = [100,100,100,100]
    exp = [0,0,0,0]
    lvl = [1,1,1,1]
    player1 = [name[0],HP[0],exp[0],lvl[0]]
    player2 = [name[1],HP[1],exp[1],lvl[1]]
    player3 = [name[2],HP[2],exp[2],lvl[2]]
    player4 = [name[3],HP[3],exp[3],lvl[3]]
    PLAYERS = [player1, player2, player3, player4]
    REGION = 'start'
    POS = '[x, y]'
    ITEMS = None
    SIGEVENTS = False
    gameData = [PLAYERS, REGION, POS, ITEMS, SIGEVENTS]
```

Out of main():

```
def playerStats():
    global Attack, Defense, Speed, MaxHP
    Attack      = [0,0,0,0]
    Defense     = [0,0,0,0]
    Speed       = [0,0,0,0]
    MaxHP   = [0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(0,4):
        Attack[i]       =   lvl[i] * 1
        Defense[i]      =   lvl[i] * 2
        Speed[i]        =   lvl[i] * 3
        MaxHP[i]        =   lvl[i] * 4

    return Attack, Defense, Speed, MaxHP
```

Comment: `key = int` is entirely redundant here.

Comment: What's wrong with `Turn = map(int, Speed + enemySpeed)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martijn Pieters already pointed out the most important issues. Try to use objects. Try to remodel the objects of your game and don't manage their attributes seperately.

I will elaborate a bit on this and maybe I can give you so some ideas.

A Character, be it a NPC or a PC, is one object of a class that could look something like this:

```
class Character:
    def __init__ (self, name, xp = 0, level = 1, hp = 4, speed = 3, atk = 1, def_ = 2):
        self.name = name
        self.xp = xp
        self.level = level
        self.hp = self.curHp = hp
        self.speed = speed
        self.atk = atk
        self.def_ = def_
        self.inventory = []
```

Now using this class you can instantiate your PCs and NPCs:

```
npcs = [Character (name) for name in ['Baldur', 'Lord Never', 'Ashyra'] ]
```

Adding methods to your class lets you interact with it, for example:

```
class Character:
    [....]
    def takeDamage (self, dmg):
        self.curHp -= min (0, dmg - self.def_)

    def gainXP (self, xp):
        self.xp += xp
        #check for level up

    def takeItem (self, item):
        self.inventory.append (item)

    def useItem (self, item):
        item.activate ()
        self.inventory.remove (item)
```

Or in order to get all your characters ordered by their speed, you can use:

```
charactersBySpeed = sorted (characters, key = -character.speed)
```

And so further and so on. The idea is really to use object oriented programming for modelling the reality (even the made-up reality of your game) in your code.

Comment: Although this is a good idea, for the OP's case a simply dictionary would have been sufficient.

Comment: True, my intention was solely to give OP a slightly broader view of which possibilities OO offers, for future projects of his or if this selfsame projects grows larger.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've looked at OO but having only some basic programming experience I didn't bother with it. I'll probably give it a go because this project is more of a learning experience than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking at *just* the speeds, look at your players and enemies, and devise a key to determine what speed goes with what player.

You didn't share any details on how you define players and speeds; I'll use a number here for now:

```
players_and_enemies = range(8)

fastest = max(players_and_enemies, key=lambda p: int(Speed[i] if i < 4 else enemySpeed[i - 4]))
```

It may well be that you can simplify this based on your data structures; if you have objects per player and enemy that have a speed attribute, for example, you can access that attribute in the key function instead.

`max()` returns the highest value by `key`; no need to sort *all* speeds if all you need is the fastest driver.

Comment: If the function could return a list of the i values of the speed (and either differentiate between player and enemy i values or I change my code to better suit it) then I could associate those i values with the players/enemies. e.g. Speed[1] corresponds to PLAYERS[1]

Comment: @BenMcAlindin: `max()` returns *one* int value, where `0` through to `3` would correspond with your `PLAYERS` list. Presumably you have a list for enemies too? The values `4-7` correspond to enemies; so you could test for `fastest > 3` and subtract `4` to get an index into your enemies list..